# How to implement a custom solution on Shopify?

Tags: automation, workflow, shopify

Customers will purchase electronic docs through the cart, and once the purchase is complete, I need to code a solution to customize the docs, and email the output to the customer.  I can have Shopify sending all the pertinent information in the order to my email, but need a server or something to "catch" that, decipher the information I need, customize my docs, and then deliver (via email) back to the customer.

Just looking for guidance on where I can learn more about building out this type of solution. Recommended applications, software, etc?

Comment: we can only help you out in coding...
rather suggesting softwares e.t.c  please look toward stackoverflow policies that how to ask questions....

Comment: Sorry, I didnt know that.  Can you help suggest the coding then?

Comment: Please show the coding where you are having problem or what display you want to show through your coding....